# Difference between sort and sorted and their reverse in python?

Tags: python, sorting, reverse, difference

I was trying to grasp my head around the difference between `.sort()` and `sorted()` and their reverse in python but I don't seem to get any. Any help?

Answer (score 3):

The difference is that sorted(l) returns a copy of l without changing it, while l.sort() changes l. See the example below:

```
l = [3, 2, 4, 5, 1, 7]
l.sort()
==> returns None, but changes l

print(l)  # As you can see, l is now sorted. 
==> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7] 

# Create an unsorted list, again
l = [3, 2, 4, 5, 1, 7]

print(sorted(l)) 
==> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7]  # sorted(l) returns a sorted list 

print(l)   # but l itself didn't change. 
==> [3, 2, 4, 5, 1, 7]
```

Comment: Did this answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

.sort() is a list method whereas sorted() is a built-in function but they effectively do the same thing.
For example...

```
my_list = [2,6,5,1,3]
my_list.sort()
print(my_list)

>>>[1, 2, 3, 5, 6]
```

The sort() method changes the my_list variable. You can add a `reverse = True` parameter into the parenthesis to reverse the list...

```
my_list = [2,6,5,1,3]
my_list.sort(reverse = True)
print(my_list)

>>>[6, 5, 3, 2, 1]
```

The sorted() function is different as it cannot chnage the my_list variable. eg...

```
my_list = [2,6,5,1,3]
sorted(my_list)
print(my_list)

>>>[2, 6, 5, 1, 3]
```

Instead you can assign the sorted(my_list) to a new variable...

```
my_list = [2,6,5,1,3]
new_list = sorted(my_list)
print(new_list)

>>>[1, 2, 3, 5, 6]
```

And if you want to reverse this list you can add `reverse = True` into the parenthesis...

```
my_list = [2,6,5,1,3]
variable = sorted(my_list, reverse = True)
print(variable)

>>>[6, 5, 3, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think .sort() is a list method which sorts the list and sorted is a builtin function which accpets some iterable object and returns its sorted copy

Answer (score 0):

The difference between `sort` and `sorted` is that `sorted(list)` returns a copy of the list without changing it, while `list.sort()` changes the list.

Therefore, `sorted` is a static method, while `sort` is a list instance method.